# EXC_BAC_ACCESS error when saving core data Boolean field

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, boolean, nsmanagedobject

I am getting a `EXC_BAC_ACCESS` error when attempting to save a TRUE value into a managed object that contains a `Boolean` attribute.

```
  id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TrafficCameraInfo"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code=%@",self.selectedTrafficCamera.code]];

    NSError *error;
    TrafficCameraInfo *cgTrafficCamera;

    cgTrafficCamera = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] lastObject];

    NSString *alertMessage;
    if (cgTrafficCamera.favourite == NO){
        cgTrafficCamera.name = @"TEST";                  <-- works ok
        cgTrafficCamera.favourite = 1;                   <-- causes an error
    } else {
        cgTrafficCamera.favourite = 0;
    }

    error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
```

The managed object interface looks like this:

```
@interface TrafficCameraInfo : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *postCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic) Boolean favourite;

@end
```

Elsewhere in my app i am updating another Boolean field by passing a 1 to it and am not encountering a problem.

Any ideas what is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Boolean is a simple, scalar, non-pointer datatype. Core Data properties are always stored as objects. The Objective-C object wrapper for numeric datatypes is NSNumber. So if `favourite` is a regular stored property, you should declare it as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *favourite;
```

Assignment would be done like this:

```
cgTrafficCamera.favourite = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]; // Obj-C style is "YES/NO" for BOOL
```

Or this if you prefer:

```
cgTrafficCamera.favourite = [NSNumber numberWithBool:1];
```

If you don't need to store the Boolean, you can leave it as such and make it a transient property. You'll probably need to get rid of the "(nonatomic)" in that case.

Comment: thanks a lot of the reply. it seems to work well but to confirm it, i need to check the value has been updated in the database. would i replace `if (cgTrafficCamera.favourite == NO)` with `if (cgTrafficCamera.favourite == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0])` or `if (cgTrafficCamera.favourite == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES])` or something else?

Comment: update: `(cgTrafficCamera.favourite == [NSNumber numberWithInt:0])` works fine. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I think in your core data attribute table you define "favorite" variable to BOOL,well that means it's an NSNumber Type,so you should set the data using NSNumber